# How to keep Froala Editor from converting whitespaces to non breaking whitespaces?

Tags: jquery, froala

Want to keep space and don't let Froala convert it to `&nbsp;`

```
this.html.insert('<a href="/">My New HTML </a>');
```

For now result is:

```
<a href="/link">My New HTML&nbsp;</a>
```

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mahma/2vrf1Lsd/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `htmlUntouched` option as `true`

> Leave the HTML inside the editor untouched without doing any special
> processing to it except HTML cleaning.

https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/#htmlUntouched

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/kxmsqn4o/)**